# CoreData Merge Conflict with single Context

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm getting no where with an issue that seems too stupid to exist. I have a UITableView that uses CoreData to generate objects.

I get an error returned here at [context save]:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

    Stop *stop=[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [context deleteObject:stop];


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
```

When I pass the stop object and a context (returned by a fresh call to ***[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];***  another view and save it like so:

```
        Stop *object= [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setStop:object];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setContext:[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];
```

---

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.stop.locationText=self.textLocationField.text;
    [self.stop.managedObjectContext save:&error];

if (![self.context save:&error]) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
```

The error is an NSMergeConflict which I understand occurs when multiple MOCs are acting on the same data. But I must be missing something fundamental because I don't believe I have two Contexts. Aren't I simply creating, modifying, and deleting the the object in a single context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error turns out that you get an NSMergeConflict when you do not have by directional relationships. So if you have a person that has Feet your feet MUST point back to a person in the relationship graph.

Comment: Seems to work for me. This is maddening because why allow non-bi-directional relationships at all if they cause NSMergeConflicts? There are other problems with CoreData too. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not need to pass the context around. You can access the property `managedObjectContext` that each `NSManagedObject` subclass provides. Thus

```
Stop *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = object.managedObjectContext;
[context deleteObject:object];
// make sure you delete the table view cell as well
[context save:&error];
```

and for updating

```
self.stop.locationText = newText;
[self.stop.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

The call to `updatedObjects` is not necessary. What did you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: That contained most of my hackery trying to figure out what is going on. So here is my clean version above:

Comment: I was unaware that I didn't need to pass around the managed object context GOOD TO KNOW, Thanks!! However I'm still having the same issue when I refactored using this methodology. 
`self.stop.locationText=self.textLocationField.text;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.stop.managedObjectContext save:&error];`
followed by:
`Stop *stop=[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = stop.managedObjectContext;
        [stop.managedObjectContext deleteObject:stop];
        if (![context save:&error]) {}` Results in same conflict